# Category still being output

Tags: categories

I've tried both of the below and category 18 is still being outputted in the category list.

**Version 1**

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" category="not 18"}
<a href="{path='shop/index'}">{category_name}</a>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

**Version 2**

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="{product_channel}" category_group="1" category="not 18"}
        <a href="{path='shop/index'}">{category_name}</a>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Strange thing is it was working previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter "category" is not valid for the channel:categories tag.

You need to use " **show**='not 18' ". I am not sure how it was working for you before.

See: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/categories.html#show

[image: Channel Category Parameters]

Comment: Thanks Cheyney, I completely missed this.

I must have swapped it at some point.

Thanks